# Docker: EXPOSE and -p

Tags: docker

I have following in Dockerfile for a spring boot project:

> EXPOSE 8081

Does it mean that container would deploy the application on its port 8081?

And then in docker run command, I need to do:

> docker run -p 8080:8081 -t imagename

So that URL http://localhost:8080 would map to container's 8081 port where application is deployed, and hence is accessible.

Comment: What is your question exactly? from docker documentation: "The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container"

Comment: I have settings as in the post. But localhost:8080 doesn't work for me. So I ma not sure about the mappings here.

Comment: Are you running docker on linux host? If yes, then paste the content of `/etc/hosts/` file?

Comment: Does your springboot project run on port 8080 or port 8081?

Comment: And is your springboot project listening on all interfaces or only loopback/127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access your service from outside docker you have to use the `-p` flag to publish the port. The `EXPOSE` instruction doesn't publish the port. You can also use the `-P` to publish every exposed port.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running
>   the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or
>   more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them
>   to high-order ports.

Comment: Thats's what I have done as mentioned in post. I have used -p 8080:8081. But I am not able to access end point doing, localhost:8080.

Comment: Your service in your container is running on port 8081 ? Can you run `docker ps` to check the mapping

Comment: 8081/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp

Comment: In your container can you run `netstat -tulpn | grep 8081`

Comment: Wait it should be the other way `0.0.0.0:8080->8081/tcp`. Maybe you can use the `-P` to publish every exposed port and check again `docker ps`

Answer (score 1):

"EXPOSE" command is particularly useless while running the container on local machine. Its for the Docker management service (Say AWS Elastic BeanStalk). when EB sees a "EXPOSE `PORT`" command in the Dockerfile, it automatically does the port mapping for you. Under the hood, it will start the container with:
`Docker run -p "targetPort:ContainerPort" image-name`

To answer your question:
Does it mean that container would deploy the application on its port 8081?
Container is not deployed at that port (8081), rather a mapping is created from: the container with PORT (8081) (running inside a linux machine) to the computer on which you access the browser.

Port mapping with -p flag is some what like this:
`Your machine port(Whatever you use on your browser): What the internal container is working on`

Comment: I appreciate the effort in this answer. However, I am unable to understand what your answer means starting from " Container is not deployed at that port (8081)...." to the end. Are you saying, when a request comes from an external client to my laptop (where the docker container is running) with destination = Laptop_IP:8081, the request is forwarded to the container on Container_IP:80 ?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from documentation for "docker run -p":

```
    ----
    docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080/tcp ubuntu bash
    ----

This binds port 8080 of the container to TCP port 80 on 127.0.0.1 of the host machine...

Note that ports which are not bound to the host (i.e., -p 80:80 instead of -p 127.0.0.1:80:80) will be accessible from the outside.
```

In your case, you mentioned:

```
    ----
    docker run -p 8080:8081 -t imagename
    ----
```

Since, localhost is not mentioned in this command, it would mean even requests from other machines reaching your machine with destination = machine_IP:8080 would be directed by your machine to container:8081. The container is expected to listen on 8081.